# Position div whit video over boostrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to position a div with a video ads, this video must go over a image and this image is inside `Bootstrap 3` container..
The video has to be responsive and resizes like the image does.
The problem is I can't adjust for all resolutions, I try to put the video inside bootstrap too and position over the image, but it did not work properly.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/byGYqV

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="container">
    <video id='video' controls="controls" preload='none' poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
        <source id='mp4' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <source id='webm' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm'>
        <source id='ogv' src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
    </video>
</div> <!-- End Normal Container -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row main-player">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <img alt="" src="https://mitofago.com.mx/sites/default/files/styles/660x320/public/0029399560.jpg" class="img-slider img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End Boostrap Container -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS in your video tag, you can adjust your values that describe below in `width` and `max-height`

```
video {
    width: 68rem;
    max-height: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PvoEjm

Comment: Thanks Nisharg, but the video has to we the same width and height as the image in the bigining

Comment: you can play with values i describe in answer but i edit my answer, check it

Comment: Thanks! i put position:absolute and top to the div without bootstrap to place it over the image, the problem is the top is fixed so when i change the resolution the video dosen 't stay in the initial position..the only solution here is using media querys? thanks!!

Comment: i don't know what are you want to say

Comment: sorry for my bad inglish Nisharg... In order to place the video on the image, I applied a position relative and a top to the div whit the video... The problem is that when I minimize the screen, the top doesn't adjust.

Comment: so do you want to put your image in your video ?

Comment: The video is an ad. When there is an ad, it must be placed there, that's why I need to be adjusted in all the resolutions covering the image. Thanks!

Comment: so your video is ad and where ad is played you want to cover your video with image ?

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to restructure some of the HTML to make the video and the image responsive.
Here's the updated Codpen link. I also had to add a small media query
[Updated codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWLPwp?editors=1100)

The image is positioned absolute over the video

```
.img-container {
 position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sagar1025 but the div whit the video has to be out for the div whit the image..

Comment: Try this link now. I just added a single wrapper for both the image and the video.
I also added the img-responsive class to the video to make it resposnive
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWLPwp?editors=1100